# How to call Play API's in-app review once in 10 days Android?

Tags: java, android, google-play-core

I implemented Play Core Library's in-app review but the review pops up when I open the app for the first time.

Is there a way to open that pop-up box only after the app has been used for 10 days or something?

I have used this code to implement it:

```
    ReviewManager manager;
    ReviewInfo reviewInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
  

        manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
        request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // We can get the ReviewInfo object
                reviewInfo = task.getResult();
                openReview();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openReview(){
        if(reviewInfo != null){
            Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
            });
        }
```

Comment: Use Shared Preference and save the first time when the app is used, check every time if the initial stored date equls 10 days then run the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

- When the app is first opened, record the date/time and save it in `SharedPreferences`
- Every time the user opens the app do the current date/time - the date/time when the app was first opened.
- If this value is more than 10 days, show the IAP Review dialog. Then you would reset the current date/time stored in `SharedPreferences`